# How to disable the CheckBox in the GridView Header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

[image: GridView]

In this GridView, I want to disable all the CheckBox in the GridView during the View Mode.
I can disable the GridView Row cells like

```
foreach (GridViewRow GVR in gvPODetails.Rows)
    {
        GVR.Cells[1].Enabled =          
        GVR.Cells[11].Enabled = false;
    }
```

But I dont know how to disable the checkbox in the HeaderTemplate of the Template Field. How to do this?

Comment: You may set checkbox `Enabled` property to `false` or explain what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @Yuriy: I edited my question please look at it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recipe:

1. Handle `OnRowDataBound` on your GridView
2. Detect whether you are iterating through the header by using `e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header` and get a reference to your checkbox control using `e.Row.FindControl(checkBoxID)`
3. Set the `Enabled` property to `False`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header ) {
        MyClass myObj = (myObj)e.Row.DataItem;
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("myCheckBox");
        cb.Enabled=false;        
    }
}
```

And if u want to do using javascript then click here
http://forums.asp.net/t/1742352.aspx/1?How+to+enable+and+disable+CheckBox+in+the+GridView+using+JavaScript+

Comment: Your code disable all checkboxes as you've written `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header )` but the asker wanted to disable the checkbox in the header so it should be as : `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header )` and then disable here. Thanks for your time.